# Dell XPS 9550 installing wifi adapter driver

Tags: linux, drivers, dell-xps, centos-7, wifi-driver

I installed CentOS 7 On Dell XPS 15 9550 but WiFi adapter doesn't work. How can I install the drivers? I read that the solution is upgrade kernel to 4.2. How can I upgrade it without Internet connection ?

Comment: Maybe simplest way is using Ethernet cable.

Comment: I know but this model have thunderbolt 3 and I haven't the adapter.

Comment: Use USB/Ethernet adapter. From 2.5 US$ on eBay, 20 US$ on Amazon, to 30 US$ on Apple Store.

Comment: Hahahaha I also know that but I ask if there is a method to do that without wait the adapter.

Comment: @Gamabunta download on another PC, transfer with USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have the new kernel, you need to get it. You did not mention that you have other PC, USB disk, Ethernet cable, USB/Ethernet adapter, but I suggested the easiest solution I can envision. :)

Actually simplest would be to connect your mobile phone to PC over USB and enable Tethering on phone - "Share your phone's mobile data connection via USB".

I use that often, as my phone WiFi sensibility is greater than of WiFi adapter in my notebook, so if WiFi signal is weak, I use phone as "adapter". :)

*Edit:*
RPM packages have dependencies, which are resolved on the fly if you are connected to internet, which is easiest way.

Other is to install all the dependencies manually, from USB or CD or DVD. If you are sure that new kernel has driver for your WiFi adapter, than you can get all needed RPM packages, and install them before kernel, and then install kernel.

Please do have in mind that kernel dependencies could have their dependencies. To be precise, almost everything depends on libc & glibc SO's and such.

Maybe you got just kernel images without kernel headers? That's usually needed.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have another PC connected, but I don't know the steps to download kernel and install it on centos.
I download rpm of latest kernel and try to install it from terminal but the installation fail.

When I go home, I post the error.